# Return ActionResult to view in mvc as a database information to webgrid with Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, return-value, webgrid

I have an ASP.NET MVC project that shows database information in a web grid, then exports that data to Microsoft Excel. I have a problem with return view as a Customer Info, my error is unable to fine matching when I right click on my action name.

```
 public ActionResult WebGridAction()
 {
        List<CustomerInfo> AllCustomerInfo = new List<CustomerInfo>();

        using (WebgridDatabaseToExcelEntities dc = new WebgridDatabaseToExcelEntities())
        {

            AllCustomerInfo = dc.CustomerInfoes.ToList();
        }

        return View(AllCustomerInfo);//I have Problem with this Return
    }

    public void GetExcel()
    {
        List<CustomerInfo> AllCustomerInfo = new List<CustomerInfo>();

        using (WebgridDatabaseToExcelEntities dc = new WebgridDatabaseToExcelEntities())
        {
            AllCustomerInfo=dc.CustomerInfoes.ToList();
        }

        WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(source: AllCustomerInfo,canPage:false,canSort:false);

        string gridData = grid.GetHtml(
                columns: grid.Columns(
    grid.Column("CustomerID", "Customer ID"),
    grid.Column("CustomerName", "Customer Name"),
     grid.Column("Address", "Address"),
     grid.Column("PostalCode", "Postal Code")
            )
            ).ToString();
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=CustomerInfo.xls");
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model List< MVCStartJumpingVersion1.CustomerInfo>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "WebGridAction";
    var grid = new WebGrid(source: Model, canPage: false);
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>WebGridView</title>
</head>
<body>
      <div>
        @grid.GetHtml(
        tableStyle: "gridtable",
        columns: grid.Columns(
        grid.Column("CustomerID", "Customer ID"),
        grid.Column("CustomerName", "Customer Name"),
         grid.Column("Address", "Address"),
         grid.Column("PostalCode", "Postal Code")

        )
        )
    </div>
    <div>
    Export to Excel:@Html.ActionLink("Click Data to Excel", "GetExcel", "WebGrid")
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hmm, this looks suspicious - `AllCustomerInfo = dc.CustomerInfoes.ToList();` what exactly `CustomerInfoes` is?

Comment: my table name in sql database in CustomerInfo